# how to get pixel values with location matrixes in row

Tags: matlab

there are 100 rows in X and Y.Each row represents a location.
and a RGB image I. 
I expect getting 100 pixels values in the red channel.
i have tried I([X Y],1)), 
but it shows 100*100 values,how can i fix it?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do! can you clarify more?
do you have an RGB image of size 100*100 and you want to get the first row in the red channel?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `I([X Y],1)` try `I(X,Y,1)` assuming that `X` is the indices into dimension 1 and Y indices of dimension 2. and not Cartesian coordinates (X,Y) where X is the horizontal axis and Y the vertical.